# Two radio buttons with the same name don't get grouped

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

My HTML:

```
<section>
  <radiogroup>
    <form>
      <input name="tabs" type="radio" />
    </form>
    <form>
      <input name="tabs" type="radio" />
    </form>
  </radiogroup>
</section>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9m96q6z/)

Radiobuttons with the same name still don't get grouped because they are inside two different `<form>` elements. Is it possible to enforce them to group?

`EDITED`: Yes, I'm aware that putting them in the same `<form>` would do the job, but I want to keep this HTML structure. I asked the question for a reason. It contains only code necessary to reproduce, but in fact the forms are much more deeply placed in `divs` etc.

Comment: I think it is impossible, since the `<form>` starts a new context and grouping can not be done using `<radiogroup>` that is an element of a form.

Comment: Isn't there some way to enforce grouping with JS for example? (I mean other than bruteforce "when this is checked, go and uncheck this"). I know how to resolve this case but I'm just curious if there is any option to force HTML to behave like this.

Comment: But this is precisely what forms are _for!_ That's what they do, they group inputs together. Whoever it is that wants to keep this HTML structure (or lack of it), I'm afraid they don't really understand what they're doing.

Comment: Yes, forms are for this, but those radio buttons are not a part of the forms, but a part of presentation as a css/js tabs. Only one tab can be displayed at a time so it works well, but only if radio buttons are grouped. In this case a radio button opening the second tab (second form) needs to be inside the first form and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can force it over Javascript.**
Just get all of your radio buttons in an array and set all of them ever time once are clicked.

```
var $radios = $('input[type=radio]');
$radios.change(function(){
  $radios.prop('checked', false);
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Quick example in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lecct8L0/

But your HTML Struktur are doesnt seems really logical for me.

Answer (score 0):

Place them in the same form like so:

```
<section>
    <radiogroup>
       <form>
           <input name="tabs" type="radio" />

           <input name="tabs" type="radio" />
       </form>
   </radiogroup>
</section>
```

And they will be grouped

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybq0z8mf/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't solve my problem, I want to keep this HTML structure.

Comment: @Senthe If you really need this HTML structure, I don't think this is possible

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one `<form>` instead:

```html
    <section>
        <radiogroup>
           <form>
             <input name="tabs" type="radio" />
             <input name="tabs" type="radio" />
           </form>
        </radiogroup>
    </section>
```

Comment: Doesn't solve my problem, I want to keep this HTML structure.